# Using Grep Find and Replace TextWrangler

Tags: grep

I hope somebody can help.

I need to change a symbol in any line containing `-` to `:` but only lines that start with `<name>`

E.G

```
<name>CT Special Forces 2 - Back in the Trenches</name>
```

Will be changed to:

```
<name>CT Special Forces 2: Back in the Trenches</name>
```

I know I can use standard find and replace on this in TextWrangler, however there are multiple lines with the same text so I only want to change every line which starts with `<name>` that has the `-` symbol to the `:` whilst leaving the rest of the text in place?

It would also be good to remove the [space] before the `-` symbol, so the colon moves to the end of the word as in my example above!

is this possible with TextWrangler, if not can anyone suggest another piece of software that will accomplish this?

Comment: `grep` can only match a pattern, it doesn't replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<name>(?:(?!</name>).)*?\K\h+-`
- Replace with: `:`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<name>              # opening tag
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!</name>)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a closing tag after
    .               # any character
)*?                 # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
\K                  # reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
\h+                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces
-                   # a hyphen
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Toto, thank you so much, that worked great! You have saved me so much time editing manually, I really appreciate you taking the time to provide a solution.

Have a great weekend.

Comment: @dantheman: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)